# ReactJS: Custom sort object by key rather than alphabetically

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the following array:

```
{
    "ALCOHOL": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Category": "ALCOHOL",
                "Name": "Beer - Can",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": 0.4,
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "748eeb60-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3"
            },
            {
                "Category": "ALCOHOL",
                "Name": "Gin & Tonic - Can",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": 0.27,
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "778f0c00-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "BREAKFAST": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Category": "BREAKFAST",
                "Name": "Chobani Pouch 100g",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": "0.100",
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "KqoCRUAm0lDIszxbvCQ2"
            },
            {
                "Category": "BREAKFAST",
                "Name": "Milk - Fresh (1L)",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": 1.065,
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "75c5e4c0-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using the following to display these items.

```
const categorizedDataFoods1 = foodValue.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { id, Category, Name, Quantity, Weight, packingLocation, bought, packed } = curr;
    if (!acc[Category]) {
      acc[Category] = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    acc[Category].items.push({ Category, Name, Quantity, Weight, packingLocation, bought, packed, id });
    return acc;
}, {});

{Object.keys(categorizedDataFoods1).map((key, index) => {
return (
{categorizedDataFoods1[key]?.items
    .sort(function (aa, ab) {
        
      var categoryA = aa.Category.toUpperCase();
      var categoryB = ab.Category.toUpperCase();
      if (categoryA !== categoryB) {
        return categoryA < categoryB ? -1 : 1;
      }
           
      var nameA = aa.Name.toUpperCase();
      var nameB = ab.Name.toUpperCase();
      if (nameA !== nameB) {
        return nameA < nameB ? -1 : 1;
      }

    })
      .map((checkbox, index) => {
{checkbox.Name}
}})})}
```

How can I custom sort these categories so in this example, Breakfast is shown before Alcohol. I also have other categories such as Lunch and Dinner - so I would want to display the items in the order of Breakfast > Lunch > Dinner > Alcohol etc

Comment: Looks like you have an object, not an array? Easiest option is probably to do `['BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH', "DINNER', 'ALCHOL'].map(key => categorizedDataFoods1[key].items...`

Comment: Thanks @BenWong - which line would I edit above?

Comment: `{Object.keys(categorizedDataFoods1).map((key, index) => {`. You're essentially replacing the array of keys `Object.keys(categorizedDataFoods1)` with your own array of keys, in the order you want them to appear.

Comment: @BenWong So replacing {Object.keys(categorizedDataFoods1).map((key, index) => { with {['BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH', "DINNER', 'ALCHOL'].map(key => categorizedDataFoods1[key].items) => {

Comment: @BenWong so i have {['BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH', 'DINNER', 'ALCOHOL'].map(key => categorizedDataFoods1[key].items)} ... what do I do now? I wanted to still show the category with the assigned item underneath and then repeat down for each of the other categories

Comment: Hey Paul, Does the code example I provided help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331388/10356909

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ben Wong, having your own list of categories in sorted order is the best choice here.

```
['BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH', "DINNER', 'ALCHOL'].map(key => categorizedDataFoods1[key].items...
```

Now, for each category, you can have a sort function to sort by name or whatever you wish to.

Comment: I understand, but dont understand how to rewrite my question to incorporate the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing our discussion in the comments, I've rewritten your code example below with as few changes as I can think of:

```js
const categorizedDataFoods1 = foodValue.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { id, Category, Name, Quantity, Weight, packingLocation, bought, packed } = curr;
    if (!acc[Category]) {
      acc[Category] = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    acc[Category].items.push({ Category, Name, Quantity, Weight, packingLocation, bought, packed, id });
    return acc;
}, {});

const sortedCategories = ['BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH', 'DINNER', 'ALCOHOL'];
{sortedCategories.map((key, index) => {
return (
{categorizedDataFoods1[key]?.items.slice()
    .sort(function (aa, ab) {
        
      var categoryA = aa.Category.toUpperCase();
      var categoryB = ab.Category.toUpperCase();
      if (categoryA !== categoryB) {
        return sortedCategories.indexOf(categoryA) - sortedCategories.indexOf(categoryB);
      }
           
      var nameA = aa.Name.toUpperCase();
      var nameB = ab.Name.toUpperCase();
      if (nameA !== nameB) {
        return nameA < nameB ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    })
      .map((checkbox, index) => {
{checkbox.Name}
}})})}
```

Comment: I get the following console error - Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable

Comment: if I keep {categorizedDataFoods1[key]?.items (instead of {[...categorizedDataFoods1[key]?.items]) .. it seems to work...

Comment: Ah yea sorry about that, you want to be careful about using using `sort` on original data, since it's a destructive/mutating function. I'll update the example to use `slice()` instead of the spread operator.

Comment: great, thanks! How do you prevent empty categories from showing?

Comment: You can use `.filter()` and just check if the category is empty in there

Comment: OK, and the .filter would go where?